# Get list of Views in Linq

Tags: linq, view

i'm using LinQ .
In SQL Server i can get List of existing Views using :

`select * from sys.views`

Above query returns :

```
Views_Email_1 
-------------
Views_Email_2
```

How to do the same using LinQ?

A View is a virtual table based on the result-set of an SQL statement.

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking. What do you mean "get List Views"?

Comment: I want to get Views using LinQ . A View is a virtual table based on the result-set of an SQL statement. you can show me , thanks you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq Syntax

```
    var viewList = from view in DBContext.sys.Views
                   select view.Name;
```

Method Syntax

```
var viewList = DBContext.sys.Views.Select(x=>x.Name);
```